# Why does my xamarin android display images and UWP doesn't?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have a very strange situation that I've lost countless hours on and I couldn't find anything on stackoverflow either.

When I create a simple image through C# on a blank page something like:

```
mainStackLayout.Children.Add(new Image() { Source = "mypic.png" });
Content = mainStackLayout;
```

After I compile this and run on my android device it works perfectly while building and running on UWP doesn't display any image at all.

I copied the same image in UWP/Assets and UWP/ root directory but still nothing.
Any ideas?

Comment: did you set BuildAction to Content?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I am very new to this (sorry hehe). Can you elaborate?

Comment: Right Click on your image file in Solution Explorer and set Build Action to Content.  As explained in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin#local-images

Comment: Okay I did what you suggested, really sounded promising but nop still nothing..

Comment: Do you have faulty exception handling that might swallow what is going wrong? Here are some articles on the mater I link a lot: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions.aspx | http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9538/Exception-Handling-Best-Practices-in-NET There is a minimal chance that WPF has some issue with the specifc way this .png is encoded.

Comment: Turns out that I had copied the pictures over from Android\Drawables to Assets folder in UWP which (I guess) copied over the BuildAction property. Setting it to Content however didn't make the pictures appear. What I did then was delete them and re-import through studio directly by right clicking the folder and Add Existing Item the issue was fixed. Kudos to @Jason but does anyone know what could have caused this in the first place?

Comment: you copied the files in Explorer, not in VS?  If you do that VS doesn't know they exist and won't include them in the build

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I copied the same image in UWP/Assets and UWP/ root directory but still nothing. Any ideas?

When you copied the pictures over from `Android\Drawables` to `Assets` folder in UWP. And  `BuildAction Property` also be copied to the UWP project. So you need to set property as `Content`.

Otherwise, the pic path is `Assets/xxx.png`. It can't be accessed with `Source = "xxx.png". So you need to modify the image source.

```
mainStackLayout.Children.Add(new Image() { Source = "Assets/icon.png" });
Content = mainStackLayout;
```

For more flexibility the `Device.RuntimePlatform` property can be used to select a different image file or path for some or all platforms, as shown in this code example

```
mainStackLayout.Children.Add(new Image() { Source = Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.UWP ? ImageSource.FromFile("Assets/xxx.png") : ImageSource.FromFile("waterfront.jpg")});
```

For more you could refer [working with image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=vswin#local-images).